# CORS angularjs file upload with IE8 support

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8, angular-file-upload

I am seeking an easy and light weight way to upload a file to a REST API using CORS in IE 8. I am using the following plugin: angular-file-upload.

Since flash doesn't support custom headers using CORS,Which means that I cannot upload a file using CORS on IE 8.

I have opened an [issue on github](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload/issues/307) on this matter, but no luck so far.

Is there a workaround solution for flash to support custom header this??
Is there any other angular module(directive) for file upload which i can use for CORS fileupload which works in IE 8??

Any help will  be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions suggested on github (similar issues as yours, different propositions) ? See [here](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload/issues?q=is%3Aissue+IE8+CORS) and [here](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/issues?q=is%3Aissue+IE8) for the two angular-file-upload libraries. This seems to be a redundant issue.

Comment: My issue with angular-file-upload is with flash not supporting custom headers with CORS.Since angular-file-upload uses flash to support in IE 8,they cannot provide workaround for me.I had a look for same issue in stackoverflow and no one answered it.Any workarounds to solve this issue will be appreciated.